# C# Process.Start is messing with URI's inside a batch file

Tags: c#-4.0, process, batch-file, uri, appdomain

This is just a quick question that I am sure someone will be able to answer quickly as I am most likely just missing something.

Lets say I have the following directory layout

```
Folder1
  -> CurrentlyRunning.EXE
  -> Folder2
     ProcessToStart.Bat
     ApplicationToStartFromBat.exe
```

This is the code inside the applications.

CurrentlyRunning.EXE:

```
        var proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                    {
                        FileName = "Folder2/ProcessToStart.Bat",
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false
                    }
            };

        proc.Start();
```

ProcessToStart.Bat:

```
START ApplicationToStartFromBat.exe
```

Now, if I run ProcessToStart.Bat by double clicking on it, it will open ApplicationToStartFromBat.exe with no problems (which is good). If I run CurrentlyRunning.EXE (which will execute the code I posted above) the BAT file fails saying it can't find my EXE (which is really weird).

If I change the BAT file to:

```
START Folder2/ApplicationToStartFromBat.exe
```

and then run CurrentlyRunning.EXE, the bat will then properly open ApplicationToStartFromBat.exe. My problem is I can not change the code inside the bat for one reason or another.

Why is `proc.Start()` causing the bat file search root directory to change, and how do I stop this from happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is to do with where the *working* directory is for your exe file.

Try using [ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) to set the correct directory for your batch file.

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "Folder2/ProcessToStart.Bat",
        WorkingDirectory = "DirectoryPath";
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    }
};
proc.Start();
```